# How to find info on UIImage in bash

Tags: php, iphone, bash, metadata, exif

I've been trying to get images from the iPhone to be displayed with the correct rotation, but I am struggling to find `EXIF`-like data on `UIImages`. For videoes I could use a program called mediainfo to find rotations of videoes (from i.e. Android phones).

```
mediainfo androidvideo.mp4 | grep rotation
```

Now I know that Android pictures are uploaded from the phone with the correct rotation to begin with, so I don't even need mediainfo for this problem. But when it comes to iPhone pictures the rotation is not automatically adjusted. So basically I need a way to automatically find the rotation from the metadata of images from the iPhone so that I can adjust them to be displayed correctly.

Note: As far as I have understood there are no `EXIF`-data for uiimages, per say. But there has to be some sort of metadata for iphone pictures as well?

Comment: Take a look at Listing 2 here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1622/_index.html

Comment: Cheers for that. But what sort of language is that? Seems like it's for iOS programming, however I am running a Linux/Debian Wheezy server. I should have specified that in the question though. It seems like you have to jump through many hoops to get the iOS metadata on anything other than iOS devices.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see the "in bash" part :) What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you export a photo taken with an iOS device it should have the usual metadata.

Comment: I am uploading images from mobile devices to a web site I have, and every picture from Android is adjusted automatically to have the correct orientation, but the images from iPhones are flipped or upside down depending on how the user held his camera. I am trying to access the metadata for rotation/orientation to flip it back into correct position automatically.